# MPMoviePlayerViewController in UIModalPresentationFormSheet Problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uimodalpresentationformsh

My problem is that i have a MPMoviePlayerViewController embeded inside a modalviewcontroller that has the formsheet atribute and when the video goes to fullscreen using the pinch or the arrows the controls dont work.

I have figured out that they dont work because only touches inside the rectangle that makes the modalviewcontroller are registered. for example, double tapping to zoom inside the rectangle works while everywhere else it doesnt.

This is a problem since the movie controls can't be used due to this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: I figured it out finally. It only worked inside because the movie player was inside of a modal view which only allowed interaction within the inside of the view. The video was going completly fullscreen so the interaction only happened in the spot where the modal view would be. To fix this I changed the modal view size on enter fullscreen and on exit fullscreen using the movie player notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. I changed the size of the modal view controller when the video was going into fullscreen.

-(void)movieDidEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification{

```
NSLog(@"did enter");

self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1500,1500);

self.navigationController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

[mpviewController moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
```

}

-(void)movieDidExitFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification{

```
NSLog(@"did exit");

UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

if (([device orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([device orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
    self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 620,540);
    self.navigationController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(384, 512);
}

else {

    self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540,620);
    self.navigationController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(384, 512);

}


[mpviewController moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

}